# Python regex, find and replace second tab character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find and replace the second tab character in a string using regex.

```
booby = 'Joe Bloggs\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
```

This works fine:

```
re.sub(r'\t',r'###', booby)
```

This regular expression to find the second tab character doesnt work as expected:

```
re.sub(r'(\t[^\t]*)\t',r'###', booby)
```

Instead of matching and replacing the second tab I get this returned:

```
'###NULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
```

I've tried it with and without prepending r'', also I have confirmed the regular expression works on regex101.com

Edit : I have swapped the original regex for glibdud's superior one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> re.sub(r'^((?:(?!\t).)*\t(?:(?!\t).)*)\t',r'\1###', booby)
'Joe Bloggs\tNULL###NULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
```

You are almost there, add `\1` before `###`

I provide another way to solve it because of the comments:

```
>>> booby.replace("\t", "###",2).replace("###", "\t",1)
'Joe Bloggs\tNULL###NULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
```

Comment: Can't see through my bleary eyes, Thanks!

Comment: @schnimmy: This answer shows bad practice of using a tempered greedy token (negating a single char) instead of the proper construct - negated character class. I suggest accepting a more elegant answer than this one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are more elegant regular expressions, but this answer specifically deals with my question about why a valid(but not very elegant) regular expression wasn't working

Comment: @schnimmy: Actually, "elegant" or not is not important. This is just an example of a very bad practice. Same as using `a(.|\n)*?b` instead  of `(?s)a.*?b`. Should never be posted, and must be deleted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I add an alternative way to solve the issue. The reason why I provieded the original answer is it solved the question OP asked. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @schnimmy i have provided an alternative solution and it is absolutely fine to check glibdud's answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @downvoter, I think the main responsibility for me is modifying OP's code and makes it work as expected. I don't think I deserve the downvote here

Answer (score 6):

You may be overthinking it a little.

```
>>> text = 'Joe Bloggs\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
>>> re.sub(r'(\t[^\t]*)\t', r'\1###', text, count=1)
'Joe Bloggs\tNULL###NULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
```

Simply match the first instance of a tab followed by any number of non-tabs followed by a tab, and replace it with everything but the final tab and whatever you want to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

## With regex

This is the shortest regex I could find :

```
import re
booby = 'Joe Bloggs\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\r\n'
print re.sub(r'(\t.*?)\t', r'\1###', booby, 1)
```

It uses non-greedy `.` to make sure it doesn't glob too many tabs.
It outputs :

```
Joe Bloggs  NULL###NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

## With split and join

The regex might get ugly if you need it for other indices. You could use `split` and `join` for the general case :

```
n = 2
sep = '\t'
cells = booby.split(sep)
print sep.join(cells[:n]) + "###" + sep.join(cells[n:])
```

It outputs :

```
Joe Bloggs  NULL###NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```