# BeautifulSoup replace line breaks with period and space

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a few links with BeautifulSoap.

Here is the relevant portion of source code of the URL I am **scraping**:

```
<div class="description">
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits
Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four. 
</div>
```

Here is my BeautifulSoap code (relevant part only) to get the text within `description` tags:

```
quote_page = sys.argv[1]
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

description_box = soup.find('div', {'class':'description'})
description = description_box.get_text(separator=" ").strip()
print description
```

Running the script using *python script.py https://example.com/page/2000* gives the following output:

```
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits
Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four.
```

How can I replace the line-break with a period followed by a space so it looks like the following:

```
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits. Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four.
```

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540424/python-regex-find-and-replace-second-tab-character):

```
html = '''<div class="description">
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits
Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four.
</div>'''
n = 2                                # occurrence i.e. 2nd in this case
sep = '\n'                           # sep i.e. newline 
cells = html.split(sep)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = sep.join(cells[:n]) + ". " + sep.join(cells[n:])
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'})
title = title_box.get_text().strip()
print (title)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits. Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four.
```

**EDIT**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://blablabla.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
description_box  = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'})
description = description_box.get_text().strip()

n = 2                                # occurrence i.e. 2nd in this case
sep = '\n'                           # sep i.e. newline
cells = description.split(sep)
desired = sep.join(cells[:n]) + ". " + sep.join(cells[n:])

print (desired)
```

Comment: Your method does work but the example I showed above is a small part of my script. The scrapper is rerun with different URLs and has multiple prints i.e. title, description, author etc. Any chance the required output can be accomplished by just changing the description part of my script? Maybe using replace or something?

Comment: @mumer91 `description` itself is a string, you may have it applied on it as well. clearly an elegant way I'd say.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused here (new to python). As you can see in question, I am getting the html from URL by running _python script.py URL_. Adding your solution in that script doesn't work for me. It does work if I define the HTML.

Comment: This answer makes more sense to me now but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the same output as before. :(

Comment: Relax, provide me the url and I can help you better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191532/discussion-between-dirtybit-and-mumer91).

Comment: Actually changing n=1 did the trick as it was the first occurrence. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @mumer91 Perfect, happy coding! :)

Comment: Actually, I would like to do this for all occurrence (in case there are more within the tag). Can you please edit it to work regardless of number of occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
description = description_box.get_text(separator=" ").rstrip("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the line and then join before you go for parse.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldata='''<div class="description">
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits
Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four. 
</div>'''
htmldata="".join(item.strip() for item in htmldata.split("\n"))
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmldata,'html.parser')
description_box = soup.find('div', class_='description')
print(description_box.text)
```

Output:

```
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbitsOf Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four.
```

**EDITED:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldata=requests.get("url here").text

htmldata="".join(item.strip() for item in htmldata.split("\n"))
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmldata,'html.parser')
description_box = soup.find('div', class_='description')
print(description_box.text.strip())
```

Comment: The HTML I provided is just an example and is coming from the URL when running _python script.py URL_. Any ideas how I can apply your solution in my script?I

Comment: ok I got your question.I'll update my answer.Please check edited section.

Answer (score 0):

Use split and join with select

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="description">
Planet Nine was initially proposed to explain the clustering of orbits
Of Planet Nine's other effects, one was unexpected, the perpendicular orbits, and the other two were found after further analysis. Although other mechanisms have been offered for many of these peculiarities, the gravitational influence of Planet Nine is the only one that explains all four. 
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
text = ' '.join(soup.select_one('.description').text.split('\n'))
print(text)
```

Comment: The HTML is provided is just an example and is coming from the URL when running _python script.py URL_. Any ideas how I can apply your solution in my script?

Comment: Is the class name consistent across urls?